# Making a REST call from a Unity Project

Tags: c#, json, rest, unity-game-engine

I need to control a robot from within Unity3D. The robot responds to these requests:

`class r0.server.httpserver.HTTPServer(*args, **kwargs)`
Bases: `pypot.server.httpserver.HTTPServer`

Bottle based HTTPServer used to remote access a robot.
The server answers to the following requests:

- `GET /motor/list.json`
- `GET /primitive/list.json`
- `GET /motor/<name>/register.json` (or `GET /<name>/register.json`) etc.

So this is an example of the documentation. I found this code example to make a REST call using C#:

```
 static string HttpGet(string url)
    {
        HttpWebRequest req = WebRequest.Create(url)
                             as HttpWebRequest;
        string result = null;
        using (HttpWebResponse resp = req.GetResponse()
                                      as HttpWebResponse)
        {
            StreamReader reader =
                new StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream());
            result = reader.ReadToEnd();
        }
        return result;
    }
```

(http://rest.elkstein.org/2008/02/using-rest-in-c-sharp.html)

So if I understood this right, I have to cast the response in json format. But how do I make the right GET call as there are many different ones. The static IP adress of the robot is 192.168.200.99, is this the URL I need to use for the requests? Thx for help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let me suggest that you get [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/) to help you determine the correct url and test your API calls.

Not knowing truly how your robot's API works, we must assume that your robot does not have a domain name.  As such, the IP address should work.  Using the provided IP address for the base url would translate as:

http://{base}/motor/list.json -> http://192.168.200.99/motor/list.json

Again [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/) can really make discovery a lot easier.

Here is an image showing a screen shot of [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/) doing a get for the OpenWeatherMap api.

[image: Postman in Action]